# Stylesheet won't link to htm

Tags: html, css

I think it has something to do with my file location, but I can't seem to get a stylesheet provided by my instructor to link to my html document.

here's the code for the html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<center>
<head>
<!-- The J-Prop Shop Sample Page
Author: Bethany Robinson
Date: 9/8/2014
-->
<title>The J Prop shop</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="JP.css">
</head>

<body>
<header>
<hgroup>
<center><h1>The J-Prop Shop</h1>
<h2>Quality Juggling and Circus Props</h2></center>
</hgroup>
</header>

<section>
<article>
<h2> Welcome</h2>
<p>If you're looking for high-quality, hand-crafted juggling and circus products, the J-Prop Shop is     the store for you. I've designed and built props for the past 35 years, and my products have been used by professional entertainers and hobbyists throughout the world. Our prices are reasonable and our quality is excellent.</p
</article>

<article>
<h2>Specials This Month</h2>
<p>The following devil sticks are available at a special discount for the entire month of September:
</p>    
<ul>
<li><b>Basic Stick </b>(<i>$19.95</i>) The easiest stick to learn with, but "grippy" enough for the   most demanding tricks.<bR>Comes in:<font color="red"> Red</font>, <font color="green"> Green</font>, & <font color="blue"> Blue</font>.
</li>
<li><b>Flower Stick</b> (<i>$24.95</i>) A graceful stick with colored tassels. Flower Sticks float slowly, making them ideal for begginners. 
</li>
<li><b>Master Stick</b> (<i>$39.95</i>) Most popular stick is shorter and heavier for fast play and more advanced tricks. Each Master Stick is available in custom colors.
</li>
<li><b>Glow Stick</b> (<i>$29.95</i>) The Glow Stick shines brightly at night (without the danger of a fire stick).
</ul>
</article>

<article>
<h2>Quality Tested</h2>
<p>Every item I create is checked and tested before being shipped out to assure perfect quality. I take pride in every one of my juggling props and want my customers to feel that same pride.
</article>  
</section>

<aside>
<h2>Customer Comments</h2>
<p>Here are a few select quotes from our happy family of customers and associates: "</p>
</aside>

<footer>
<address>
<small>The J-Prop Shop<br> 541 West Highland Drive<br>Auburn, NE 04210<br>(207)-555-9001</small>
</address>
</footer>

</body>
</center>
</hmtl>
```

It's a simple code really, but for whatever reason the stylesheet won't load when I view it in the browser.
Both the .css and .html files are located in a folder on my desktop.
What is the problem??

Comment: is `css` file in same path as `html` page?

Comment: Hit the F12 key in your browser. What errors does it list? Also, `<center>` is [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center), and only belongs **within** the `<body>` element if you insist on using it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using an Operating System with a case-sensitive file system? In that case check the css file is named `JP.css` and not `jp.css`.

You haven't mentioned your browser's name and version. Try correcting the `</hmtl>` to `</html>` and removing the `<center>` tag between `<html>` and `<head>` tag.

Comment: I changed both things and it's still not working, and I'm using Google Chrome Version 37.0.2062.120, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If it is in another folder, make sure to mention it as:

```
href="css/index.css"
```

Answer (score 0):

Clear your browsers cache. I've had issues like that with chrome.